# UWP - Automatic if statement with sequence condition

Tags: c#, if-statement, uwp

I have a condition where if file = 2016, then folder_id = 1, if file = 2015 then folder_id = 2, like so on. How do I apply the if statement automatically (instead of entering one by one) with C# language?

Comment: Do you have list of file and folder ids?

Comment: yes, I have. I only need to check it if 2016 is 1, if 2015 is 2, and so on

Answer (score 1):

Assuming files and folder ids are sequential...

```
var increment = 1;

var currentFile = 2016;
var currentFolder = 1;
var minFile = 2000;//change this to whatever you need

while(minFile <= currentFile){
    //do your work

    currentFile -= increment;
    currentFolder += increment;
}
```

Comment: How do you check and insert database statement according to the currentfolder? Because I tried it instead to become a folder_id afterwards.

Comment: Still stuck on this? Use `string.format("folder_{0}", currentFolder);` to create the folder name or even better, open a new more-specific question